# Add columns or making new table for ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql

We have a games' table, each game just add one time in this table but many of them have several platforms like PC, PS3, X360 and ... . we want to add different release date for games that have different release date for different platforms, for example Resident Evil 6 which first release on PS3 and X360 and then in another date release on PC.

Also, we have different type of release date like exact date, for example 29 October 2012, or Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4 2014, or TBA 2014 or just TBA ...

Now, my question is there:

Is it better to add field as much as the number of platforms and put release dates in there and select all of them by LEAST() and GREATEST()?

Or making separate table which has game id, release date and platforms?

Which one is easier and lighter for database?

Note that the possibility of filling the games' table is 200 games a year.

Also note that we want to show this game two times in our upcoming page if it release two times for different platforms. and show just one time if release for all of its platforms in same date.

---

This is my first model:

|  id  | platform              | rdate       | rtype   |  rdate_pc    |  rdate_x360 | rdate_ps3   |

|  27  | pc,xbox360,ps3 | 20140306 | pc=Q4 |  20140000  |  20140306   |  20140400   |

---

and this is my second model:

|  id  | platform  | rdate       |  rtype |

|  27  | pc         | 20140000 | Q4    |

|  27  | ps3       | 20140400 | TBA  |

---

So which one is better?

Comment: if by better you mean more capable of scaling long term the second approach.  like data should not be duplicated and the concept of release date is unique to platform and game so I would probably have a games table, a platform table and a platform games table which contains the release date.  A separate row would exist in platform games for each game/platform/release date.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you want to limit one entry to a field (not having Xbox, PS3 as a single entry). For this, you should create another table that links a platform to a game; the release date for that platform can also be kept here. You would have something like your second table, with another table listing all of the games by ID.

Also, since you said there would be around 200 games per year in the dB, it may be worth looking into a NoSQL database, such as Mongo. These databases allow you to have fields that are associated with some entries in a table, but not others and would allow you to filter based on this.

Also note that the SQL `LEAST` and `GREATEST` queries won't work with a date mixed with something such as Q4, I don't believe.

Answer (score 0):

The second model is going to be much more flexible. For one thing, with the first model, if you add more platforms you will need to add another rdate_* field for each new platform you add.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a database structure with at least three tables, something like the following:

```
Games
(
Id
Name
--any other relevant information, such as ESRB rating that will apply
)

Platforms
(
Id
Name
--any other relevant information
)

Game_Platforms
(
GameId
PlatformId
ReleaseDate
--any other relevant information
)
```

As other posters have noted, this allows for more flexibility when new platforms are added, release dates change (or are cancelled completely).